# Why I am unable to break my outer for loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, label

Please check the below `Android` code

```
public void setTitles(final List<AppDataBean> appDataBeanList){
        dataBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
        outer:for(a=0;a<appDataBeanList.size();a++)
        {
            appDataBeanListIndex=a;
            //Get data from the Bean list
            final AppDataBean appDataBean = appDataBeanList.get(a);
            if (InternetConnectivity.isConnectedToInternet(context)==true){
                try {
                    LinkReader linkReader = new LinkReader();
                    linkReader.onFinish(new LinkReader.OnTaskCompleted() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<DataBean> list) {
                            inner:for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                if (InternetConnectivity.isConnectedToInternet(context)== true){
                                    //Gather all information into DataBean
                                    DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
                                    dataBean.setTitle(list.get(i).getTitle());

                                    //Add the DataBean to the bean list
                                    dataBeanArrayList.add(dataBean);


                                }

                                if(i==4)
                                {
                                    break outer;;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In here,notice how I have labelled the for loops as `outer` and `inner`. Inside the second loop I am trying to break the `outer` loop when a certain condition is met, but it is not working because it is giving the compile error "`undefined label: outer`".

Why is this? I tried to wrap the `outer` content with curly bracers, which then covers `inner` section too, and I tried without the curly bracers, the same error.

Comment: Just a small comment, you have WAY too many nested loops and ifs in this method. You might want to simply and clean up your code a bit in order to help with debugging.

Comment: That is an ***anonymous* inner `class`**. The block isn't local to that class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: There we go, how to handle this then?

Comment: The loop will have completed long before that `onFinish` actually triggers so I'm not sure why you're trying to `break` it.

Comment: Yes, that argument is right. I am trying to break it because I am trying to read just 4 records. But yes, I can adjust the loop index directly, hmm, didn't come to my mind still now....

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638321/how-to-exit-two-nested-loops

Comment: take a field `check_inner = false;` and `on load finished` make `check_inner = true;` and finally in tge outer loop make a checking `if(!check_inner) a--;` i think this will work..update if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not
>   transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred
>   to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated)
>   statement.

which means that you cannot treat it as `goto`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960484/2458858) post gives following example:

```
first:
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  second:
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j ++ )
  {
    break xxx;
  }
}

third:
for( int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {

}
```

You could replace `xxx` with `first` or `second` since both loops are being executed, but replacing xxx with third won't compile.

**Now in your case**, an `anonymous inner class` is getting created here:

```
linkReader.onFinish(new LinkReader.OnTaskCompleted() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<DataBean> list) {
```

and you are trying to break within the scope of this inner class:

```
if(i==4)
{
   break outer;
}
```

If you move your condition outside the scope of this inner class, it would work.